# Assign or construct a std::string given multiple char* strings

Tags: c++, string

When initializing a `std::string` like this:

```
std::string { "hello" + " c++ " + " world" };  // error
```

It errors because `const char*` cannot be added.

Meanwhile:

```
std::string { "hello" " c++ " " world" };  // ok
```

It works thanks to compiler magic.

And then, according to Google's coding-guide, I use `constexpr` since statements should be not be hard coded:

```
constexpr const char* HELLO = "hello";
constexpr const char* LANG_CPP = " c++";
constexpr const char* WORLD = " world";
```

Now things are different:

```
std::string str { HELLO LANG_CPP WORLD };  // error
```

Implicit concatenation doesn't work anymore.

Eventually, I wrote code like this:

```
std::string str = HELLO;
str += LANG_CPP;
str += WORLD;
```

Other options like below are not appealing to me:

```
std::string str = std::string(HELLO) + std::string(LANG_CPP) + std::string(WORLD);
```

```
std::string str = HELLO + std::string(LANG_CPP) + WORLD;
```

Do you have alternatives that are better looking?

**Update**: I have simplified the code. In order to focus on the matter I am concerned with.

My original code looked like this:

```
sql = "delete from " TABLE_NAME ";";
```

```
sql = "insert into " TABLE_NAME "values(" var1 ", " var2 ");";
```

By the way, the result of concatenation is not required to be a `string`, `const char*` is ok, too.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using C++14 or later you can write

```
sql = "delete from "s + TABLE_NAME + ";"s;
```

Comment: first of all thx for your quick advice. if i want to use string literal then implicit concatenation just fit. the thing is to use (constexpr) const char *

Comment: You want `TABLE_NAME` to be a `constexpr const char*`? The above code works in that case.

Comment: "delete from " is also hard coded in this case.. i think it need to be replaced like `constexpr const char * DELETE_COMMAND = "delete from ";`

Comment: Note that you need `using namespace std::string_literals;` to use the [`""s` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator""s).

Answer (score 1):

The only way to make this work:

```
std::string str { HELLO LANG_CPP WORLD };
```

Is to use *preprocessor* `#define` macros instead of `constexpr` variables, eg:

```
#define HELLO "hello"
#define LANG_CPP " c++"
#define WORLD " world"
```

So that the *compiler* sees this:

```
std::string { "hello" " c++ " " world" };
```

You have already covered most other uses of `const char*`/`std::string` concatenations, but one you didn't mention is `std::ostringstream`, eg:

```
#include <sstream>

constexpr const char* HELLO = "hello";
constexpr const char* LANG_CPP = " c++";
constexpr const char* WORLD = " world";

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << HELLO << LANG_CPP << WORLD;
std::string str = oss.str();
```